# A point inside a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

[image: Convex quadrilateral]

I have deduced the fact that KL = LM by proving that the diagonals of the quadrilateral are equal. BUT, I can't understand how to proceed further and prove the triangle KLM to be equilateral.

/[I got the given question from the Facebook page created recently by my maths teacher](https://www.facebook.com/Mathematics-Gems-by-Ajay-Lakhina-603105973366261/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle $BOD$ is obtained from $AOC$ with a $120°$ rotation, hence lines $AC$ and $BD$ form angles of $120°$ and $60°$. Segments $KL$ and $LM$, which are parallel to those lines, thus also form an angle of $60°$, which implies that $KLM$ is equilateral.

EDIT. The same by angle chasing.

Let angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in congruent triangles $AOC$ and $BOD$ be defined as in the diagram below. We have then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+120°=180°$, that is:  $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=60°$. On the other hand, as the angles in quadrilateral $COBN$ sum up to $360°$ ($N$ being the intersection of diagonals $AC$ and $BD$) we have: $\angle CNB+\alpha+\beta+\gamma+240°=360°$, whence: 
$\angle CNB=120°-\alpha-\beta-\gamma=60°$.

But $ML\parallel BD$ and $KL\parallel AC$, hence $\angle KLM=\angle CNB=60°$.

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific and rigorous in your proof? I can't comprehend how AC and BD form an angle of 60°. Just a beginner, I would love to see a more complete proof!

Comment: Two intersecting lines form two supplementary angles. In this case we know that one angle is 120°, hence the other one is 60°.

Comment: But the line BOD is not straight.

Comment: Actually, do you have a different approach? I am sorry but I just can't visualise this and my approach has always been very technical.

Comment: Didn't you study rotations? Triangles $AOC$ and $BOD$ are connected by a rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of your rudimentary approach. Just became interested in maths, and I can only understand by writing down the congruencies, angles, etc. and labelling everything. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: If $P$ is the intersection of the diagonals, you can also show that $\angle APD=60°$ by angle chasing, but it's a lot more tedious.

Comment: Rotations ARE NOT rudimentary!

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsAngleChasing.shtml

Comment: I just saw this link, and realised I know angle chasing! But, how to find the angle in the given problem? Please tell me this tedious approach, it would save me and you a lot of time after that!! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain me the tedious angle chasing? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I also realised that the angles in a non - convex polygon also add up to 360°! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The figure is not unique in a sense that you can raise the point $A$ to get an isosceles trapezium $ABCD$ and still meet all the requirements. Then $\measuredangle KLM=\measuredangle CQB=60$, because they are opposite angles of the parallelogram.